# Code highlighting for sqlite3

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[It looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause) there is code highlighting in place for the tag `sql` and possibly even `sqlite`. Can we get this code highlighting to apply to questions with the tag `sqlite3` as well? For example:

[sqlite3: read-only main database and ATTACH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637790/sqlite3-read-only-main-database-and-attach)

Comment: Add the `sql` tag to the question, and you'll get the highlighting you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed, but these aren't _my_ questions. Wouldn't it be better to have the sqlite3 tag also have syntax highlighting when it is the _only_ tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the code highlighting to `lang:sql` for the SQLITE3 tag.